# Kafka Streams - kafka-streams-application-reset.sh sending wrong API version

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed-computing, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka 0.10.0.1 adds the ability to reset a Kafka Streams app using a script called [kafka-streams-application-reset.sh](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh)

Confluent has some good documentation on this script [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/).

Unfortunately, running the script locally results in an error:

```
$ bin/kafka-streams-application-reset --application-id my-streams-app \
                                      --input-topics my-input-topic \
                                      --intermediate-topics rekeyed-topic \
                                      --bootstrap-servers brokerHost:9092 \
                                      --zookeeper zookeeperHost:2181

# output
ERROR: Request GROUP_COORDINATOR failed on brokers List(...)
```

Also, the following line appears in the broker logs:

```
kafka.network.InvalidRequestException: Error getting request for apiKey: 3 and apiVersion: 2
```

From what I can tell, it looks like the client is making an invalid request, but I'm unsure why this happening. Our brokers are still on 0.9.0 so I'm not sure if that's the issue, but it appears to be [a meta data request](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3b4c347949c02b1e2b1dd473deda0f8d2304d027/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/protocol/ApiKeys.java#L26) based on the `apiKey` value in the broker log.

Could someone please let me know why this might be happening and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Streams is based on version 0.10 and does not work for 0.9.

The same is true for `bin/kafka-streams-application-reset` tool. It uses a 0.10 `KafkaClient` internally and requires a 0.10 broker.

In general, only Kafka brokers but not Kafka clients are backward compatible, i.e., brokers do work with older clients but clients do not work with older brokers. This might improve in future released so. See [KIP-97: Improved Kafka Client RPC Compatibility Policy](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-97%3A+Improved+Kafka+Client+RPC+Compatibility+Policy)

The error message -- even if not very descriptive and hard to understand -- is telling you that you try to connect to a broker that does not understand the new client.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I do disagree that the error message is exactly telling me that the broker doesn't understand the new client, it just says that there was an error for a meta data request `apiKey: 3` using `apiVersion: 2`, but doesn't actually specify what the error is exactly (i.e. `InvalidRequestException: Error getting request` is not very specific). Either way, thanks for the answer, I'll mark it as correct

Comment: I agree. The error message is not very descriptive... :/

Comment: Just updated my answer: c.f. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-97%3A+Improved+Kafka+Client+RPC+Compatibility+Policy